# TeX Conditional in Lua

Tags: luatex, context, expansion

Why can I use

```
\startluacode
context.mymacro("\noexpand\\iftrue")
\stopluacode
```

But not

```
\startluacode
context.mymacro([[\noexpand\iftrue]])
\stopluacode
```

Or not

```
\startluacode
context.mymacro([[\unexpanded{\iftrue}]])
\stopluacode
```

Or not

```
\startluacode
context.mymacro("\luaescapestring{\normalunexpanded{\iftrue}}")
\stopluacode
```

Where I believe `\iftrue` to be an expandable primitive.

*edit*

```
\def\mymacro#1{%
    \let\mycond#1%
    \show\mycond}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\startluacode<code>\stopluacode` translates roughly to:

```
\begingroup
  <catcode settings> (basically verbatim, but \ is catcode 0)
  <shorthands> (\\ is defined to be the two backslash characters, as
    well as \|, \-, \(, \), \{, \}, etc.)
\normalexpanded {\endgroup \noexpand \directlua {<code>}}
```

and what's biting you here is that the `<code>` is expanded *twice*: once by `\normalexpanded` (the `\expanded` primitive), and once more by `\directlua`.

The first one works because once the expansion of `\normalexpanded` is over, you are left with `\directlua{context.mymacro("\\iftrue")}`, which does what you want. Note that since `\\` is defined to expand to `\12\12`, you don't need `\noexpand` there, so you can simplify the first example to:

```
\startluacode
context.mymacro("\\iftrue")
\stopluacode
```

The second one:

```
\startluacode
context.mymacro([[\noexpand\iftrue]])
\stopluacode
```

doesn't work because the `\noexpand` disappears with `\normalexpanded`, and you are left with `\directlua{context.mymacro([[\iftrue]])}`, and then `\directlua` expands the `\iftrue` too early. You'd need two rounds of `\noexpand`:

```
\startluacode
context.mymacro([[\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\iftrue]])
\stopluacode
```

The third one:

```
\startluacode
context.mymacro([[\unexpanded{\iftrue}]])
\stopluacode
```

doesn't work for three reasons: first, in ConTeXt `\unexpanded` is the `\protected` primitive, not `\unexpanded`. You need `\normalunexpanded` here. Second, inside `\startluacode` braces are catcode 12, so `\normalunexpanded` will throw a `Missing { inserted` error. And third is the same as above: you have two rounds of expansion, so you need two `\normalunexpanded`:

```
\everyluacode\expandafter{\the\everyluacode
  \catcode`\{=1 \catcode`\}=2\relax} % catcode setting to have braces be braces
\startluacode
context.mymacro([[\normalunexpanded{\normalunexpanded{\iftrue}}]])
\stopluacode
```

The fourth one:

```
\startluacode
context.mymacro("\luaescapestring{\normalunexpanded{\iftrue}}")
\stopluacode
```

doesn't work for the same reason as above: braces are catcode 12, so `\luaescapestring` never sees the `{` it needs and throws a `Missing { inserted` error. You need to set the right catcodes first:

```
\everyluacode\expandafter{\the\everyluacode
  \catcode`\{=1 \catcode`\}=2\relax} % catcode setting to have braces be braces
\startluacode
context.mymacro("\luaescapestring{\normalunexpanded{\iftrue}}")
\stopluacode
```

Comment: Don't the catcodes expire after `\endgroup`? And what benefit is there to using `\normalexpanded`?

Comment: @user19087 They do, but at the time the `\(normal)expanded` grabs the `<code>` as argument, the catcodes in force are the Lua ones, so everything is tokenized as catcode 12. I don't know for sure why ConTeXt uses `\normalexpanded` there, but I'd guess it's to use the shorthands defined earlier without having to execute the Lua code itself in a group. This allows you, to use, for example, `\startluacode context.mymacro("\\iftrue")\stopluacode`